# Eclipse View Table that displays a subset of entries

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am looking to add a table to my Eclipse view. I need that table to display no more than 25 items at a time. Then I would like to have a next/previous feature that will show the prior 25 or the next 25 items. I created a custom class to hold the data for a table item, store these into a hash map, and add the first 25 values to the table. I then added buttons to the view to clear the table and add the next/prior 25 values from the map based on the button the user pressed. My question is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I think this would fit better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual table to display the data. See
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-Virtual/Virtual-in-SWT.html